# How to inject @Value into a setter?

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to inject a `@Value` property into a setter of a `@Service`?

```
@Service
public class DateService {
    private DateTimeFormatter dtf;

    public void setDtf(@Value("${spring.jackson.date-format}") String format) {
        dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    }
}
```

Problem: the setter is never invoked. But how can I inject a `String` property and directly instantiate the `DateTimeFormatter` from it?

I also tried using `SpEL`, but the following format is not correct.

```
@Value("#{T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(${spring.jackson.date-format}))}")
private DateTimeFormatter dtf;
```

Comment: you already tried to use contructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring value injection unable to get value from properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545498/spring-value-injection-unable-to-get-value-from-properties)

Comment: "private" setter is not a setter. 
change "private" to "public" and let Spring do it job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `DateService` has just one constructor, you can just use constructor injection instead:

```
@Service
public class DateService {
    private DateTimeFormatter dtf;

    @Autowired
    public DateService(@Value("${spring.jackson.date-format}") final String format) {
        this.dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so the catch here was the missing `@Autowired` annotation on the setter.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why [@sxc-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10416462/sxc-dev) answer is down voted cause it is better the using constructor if you can't for some reasons and it IS working.

```java
 @Service
 public class DateService {
        private DateTimeFormatter dtf;
    
        @Autowired
        public void setDtf(@Value("${spring.jackson.date-format}") String format) {
            dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
        }
    }
```

also that solution works too

```java
@Service
public class DateService {
        private DateTimeFormatter dtf;
    
        @Value("${spring.jackson.date-format}")
        public void setDtf(String format) {
            dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
        }
}
```

its very useful way if you have lombok and other services to inject

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgConstructor
public class DateService {
        private final SomeService someService;
        private DateTimeFormatter dtf;
    
        @Value("${spring.jackson.date-format}")
        public void setDtf(String format) {
            dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about add your @Value annotation not on setter method but just over member declaration? This should work

```
@Service
public class DateService {
    @Value("${spring.jackson.date-format}")
    private DateTimeFormatter dtf;

    public void setDtf(String format) {
        dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    }
}
```

You probably don't even need a setter method at all unless you explicitly use it

Answer (score 0):

Adding @Autowired to setter should work.

```
  @Service
    public class DateService {
        private DateTimeFormatter dtf;
    
        @Autowired
        public void setDtf(@Value("${spring.jackson.date-format}") String format) {
            dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
        }
    }
```