# How to set @value property java

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pact

I was writing pact provider test which validate the incoming request from consumer and i have used custom constraint validator for that like

```
public class MaxRecipients implements
    ConstraintValidator<MaxRecipientsSize, Collection> {

  @Value("${recipient.max.size}")
  private Integer recipientMaxSize;


  @Override
  public void initialize(MaxRecipientsSize constraintAnnotation) {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Collection value, ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {
    if (isEmpty(value)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
```

Here when control comes, the value of recipientMaxSize becomes null, i have configured the property in  application properties and property source.
Can someone help on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring value injection unable to get value from properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545498/spring-value-injection-unable-to-get-value-from-properties)

Comment: You also need to pass properties into test class. For example using `@TestPropertySource`. More details here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source

Comment: How do you register properties file?

Comment: I have already registered it using property source and it shows the value when used in test class but when the control goes to service level, it shows the value as null

Comment: pls post more related code and application.yml

Answer (score 0):

I think your class MaxRecipients lacks the annotation @Component or similar. Because of that, @Value is not filled through Spring.

Comment: i have used @component also

Comment: Then your applications.properties / application.yml is not loaded properly. Please add your complete code (including @Component) and your application.properties/yml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350537/inject-service-in-constraintvalidator-bean-validator-jsr-303-spring has an answer.